# Change Monitor ID on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-quadro

I'm trying to configure a workstation with 3 monitors used for viewing DICOM images from a PACS application to display content correctly on each display. The workstation has 2 monitors attached to one graphics card plus a TV connected to another. All are NVIDIA Quadro cards.

The software itself determines what to display based on server stored workstation profiles. The configuration is stored with the monitor identification numbers and not based on which monitor is configured as primary or what position they are in.

At the moment, the 2 monitors are 3 and 2, TV is 1. The login screen shows on the lowest number display (1). Once logged in the list page shows on the specified display. The way the software is made, image viewing areas are configured with a starting monitor and number of monitors to display on. IE I'd set it as monitor 2 and to display across 2 monitors (2+3).

Because the way Windows has decided to number the ID for each display, I can't configure this station correctly. Primarily I need the login screen to appear on a monitor instead of a TV (it's not configurable, always defaults to monitor 1). Is there any way to change the ID number of each monitor?

I've discussed it with the manufacturer of the software but it's like getting blood from a stone.

Comment: Is it impossible to edit the server stored workstation profile?

Comment: Editing options are limited to Main app window screen, starting screen for images and number of screens to show images. No settings will affect which display the login screen shows on which is the biggest issue as the TV will not always be on. Teaching doctors to disable/enable a screen is an uphill battle.